# Pyspark: how to convert hours with decimal to hh:mm

Tags: apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have the following sample dataframe that has object ids and total hours. the decimal values are minutes converted into a fraction of an hour.

```
# +----+----+--------+
# |col1|total_hours  |
# +----+-------------+
# |obj1| 48387.837   |
# |obj2| 45570.0201  |
# |obj3| 39339.669   |
# |obj4| 37673.235   |
# |obj5| 3576        |
# |obj6| 15287.9999  |
# +----+-------------+
```

I want to show the total hours in hours: minutes format.

**desired output**:

```
# +----+----+--------+
# |col1|total_hours  |
# +----+-------------+
# |obj1| 48387:50    |
# |obj2| 45570:01    |
# |obj3| 39339:40    |
# |obj4| 37673:14    |
# |obj5| 3576:00     |
# |obj6| 15288:00    |
# +----+-------------+
```

in SQL I am able to do this with the following function :

```
  hr = trunc(col1);
  minutes = round(hr -trunc(hr)* 0.6, 2);

  hours_minutes= trim(replace(to_char(hr + minutes ,'999999999990.90'),'.',':'));
```

How can this be done in Pyspark?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is going to require string manipulation given that simple formatting can't work.
This is picking up the mod of the number, multiplying it by 60, formatting both and then concatenating:

```
df.withColumn('total_hours_str', 
   f.concat(f.regexp_replace(f.format_number(f.floor(df.total_hours), 0), ',', ''), 
            f.lit(':'),  
            f.lpad(f.format_number(df.total_hours%1*60, 0), 2, '0'))).show()
```

Output:

```
+----+-----------+---------------+
|col1|total_hours|total_hours_str|
+----+-----------+---------------+
|obj1|  48387.837|       48387:50|
|obj2| 45570.0201|       45570:01|
|obj3|  39339.669|       39339:40|
|obj4|  37673.235|       37673:14|
|obj5|     3576.0|        3576:00|
+----+-----------+---------------+
```

EDIT:

As you're having fractional values that end up being rounded to a whole hour, I suggest you round before processing the column:

```
df.withColumn('rounded_total_hours', f.round(df['total_hours'],2))\
  .withColumn('total_hours_str', 
      f.concat(f.regexp_replace(f.format_number(f.floor(f.col('rounded_total_hours')), 0), ',', ''), 
               f.lit(':'),  
               f.lpad(f.format_number(f.col('rounded_total_hours')%1*60, 0), 2, '0'))).show()
```

Which produces:

```
+----+-----------+-------------------+---------------+
|col1|total_hours|rounded_total_hours|total_hours_str|
+----+-----------+-------------------+---------------+
|obj1|  48387.837|           48387.84|       48387:50|
|obj2| 45570.0201|           45570.02|       45570:01|
|obj3|  39339.669|           39339.67|       39339:40|
|obj4|  37673.235|           37673.24|       37673:14|
|obj5|     3576.0|             3576.0|        3576:00|
|obj6| 15287.9999|            15288.0|       15288:00|
+----+-----------+-------------------+---------------+
```

Comment: This code does not solve the problem completely, as you can see it increase the hours by 1 , I tried to change using floor, but the code fails when I have values like 15287.99 where the output is 15287.60, please help in refactoring it so that it doesn't raise the number by 1 and also takes into account when the minutes reaches 60

Comment: Thanks, didn't notice that. `format_number` is rounding, so this is now `floor`ing it first.

Comment: Thanks, still 1 more is required for 15287.99 the output is 15287:60 instead of 15288:00, please review & I have updated the desired output example for this

Comment: @SS_flair that's not part of the test data

Comment: sorry, I didn't realize it unitl I ran the code on the whole dataset, i have updated the sample dataset

Comment: Then that makes conflicting logic. If it's a fraction, it's a fraction, not a whole hour. If you have to do this, then I suggest you first round to 2 decimal places before running this code, like `f.round(df['total_hours'],2)` for `total_hours`, or make a new column with this value and do the string manipulations on the new column. You should round before doing this, because this expects a true fraction, not a fraction that will turn into a whole unit as part of the new roundings.

Comment: @SS_flair I've also added an implementation for that option to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If your desired datatype is a string then this can be done with string concat.

Steps:

1. Extract the hours by creating a column that casts `total_hours` to
   `IntegerType()`
2. Extract the fraction of hours by subtracting that value from the `total_hours`
3. multiply that decimal by 60 to get the number of minutes
4. casts to string and concat with a `:` seperator.

Code:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType
from pyspark.sql.functions import concat_ws

df = df.withColumn('total_hour_int', df['total_hours'].cast(IntegerType())
df = df.withColumn('hours_remainder', df['total_hours']-df['total_hour_int'])
df = df.withColumn('minutes', df['hours_remainder']*60)
df = df.withColumn('minutes_full', df['minutes'].cast(IntegerType())
df = df.withColumn('total_hours_string', concat_ws(':', df['total_hour_int'], df['minutes_full'])
```

Comment: This code works for some and not for all. For example : 30503.1497 the output is 30503:8 while the correct answer should be 30503:09

Comment: @SS_flair - i'd say it's up for debate on what the desired result would be. My clock does not show 12:00 when the time is 11:59:31.

Comment: the output i am getting is 30503.8, this should be handled if the minutes crosses 60 right, correct me if i am wrong